# WebAPI + APIController with structureMap

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, structuremap

Im trying to use StructureMap to initialize my ValuesController that derivate from ApiController but i'm getting an exception that says:

The IControllerFactory '...CustomControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'api'.

Here is the code..

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;

        return (Controller)ConcretizationsManager.GetInstance(controllerType);
    }
}
```

basically ConcretizationsManager is a wrapper of StructureMap..
This method always runs ok for Controllers of Controller type, but for APIController dont.

Anyone to get me to the right direction?
Very thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For the Web API I am using Custom *ServiceActivator* like this (i.e. different factory then for MVC):

```
public class ServiceActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    public ServiceActivator(HttpConfiguration configuration) {}    

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request
        , HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller = Factory.CreateInstance(controllerType) as IHttpController;
        return controller;
    }
}
```

*Where Factory is my wrapper of the Sturcturemap API*

And in the `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs` I do register that like this:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new ServiceActivator(config));
```

Comment: Greate ;) I am happy with that as well ;)

Comment: In my own app it was `ObjectFactory.GetInstance` instead of `Factory.CreateInstance`

Comment: *Just a note, you are right. We are using the Abstraction, Custom `Factory`, with its provider, wrapping the StructureMap. But it could be as you say...*

Comment: ObjectFactory is marked as obsolete, but Container.For<IHttpController>() returns an error because there is not a parameterless constructor what are my options?

Comment: @Brian *You should issue your own question to get answer how to use container...* I am for example using Custom IRegistry `MyRegistry : Registry` which is place for all settings. Then I can build `new Container(new MyRegistry());` and even more of them...

Comment: I am running 5.2.2 and SM 3.1.4.143 - all is working and defined above *(and also, behind custom `Factory` are few SM `StructureMap.Container` instead of obsolete `ObjectFactory`)*

Comment: I just had to implement WebApi 5.2.2 on top of MVC 5.2.2 so I just used package "StructureMap.WebApi2" which worked out of the box. There is no need for custom code.

 If you have *catch all route in MVC make sure you register WebAPI (routes) BEFORE MVC ones. I just got stuck for a while getting 404s instead of hitting WebAPI and though problem was with DI.

Answer (score 2):

There is first party support for this with StructureMap 3

> nuget install Structuremap.WebApi2

StructureMap 4 has been released and could be used also, however [there may be slight tweaks needed](https://twitter.com/jeremydmiller/status/672496264693477376). I have not confirmed for myself.