# How to get instance of dependency resolver in ASP.NET web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

How can I get the dependency resolver instance in web api? In asp.net mvc I can do `DependencyResolver.Current`, is there an equivalent in web api?

Comment: You probably already know this, but I have to provide the obligatory warning: You should be allowing the dependency resolver to inject the necessary dependencies into your classes, using the Api Controller as your context root, rather than going in search of the dependency resolver.

Comment: yeah, the reason I need to use the resolver is inside a custom model binder, which will be set using the modelbinder attribute, instead of a model binder provider, so it will be instantiated with a paramterless constructor, so I need to use service location to get the dependencies.

Comment: Just a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919753/. Please, take it as another view - why to avoid `IDependencyResolver`. ServiceLocator could/should be seen as antipattern http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ignore what people are saying about being an anti-pattern. You won't get full DI coverage, especially with these young technologies. For example, at the time of writing, `NInject` has no support for injecting into middlewares.

To answer your question, the dependency resolver for a request is available through `HttpRequestMessage.GetDependencyScope()`. You can also use `HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver` however beware that this one is not properly scoped for the request being executed.

I would recommend checking the documentation for the specific IOC implementation.

Answer (score 3):

When using Ninject in Web API, you can use GlobalConfiguration.Configuration. For instance for IUserService:

```
(IUserService)System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IUserService))
```

Hope this helps you.