# How to use Container instead of ObjectFactory in StructureMap ServiceActivator?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, structuremap

When implementing DI in WebAPI with StructureMap, we used the **ServiceActivator** found in

- [Configuring Dependency Injection with ASP.NET WebAPI 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919753/configuring-dependency-injection-with-asp-net-web-api-2-1)
- [WebAPI + APIController with structureMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896758/webapi-apicontroller-with-structuremap)

---

```
public class ServiceActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    public ServiceActivator(HttpConfiguration configuration) {}    

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request,
           HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as IHttpController;
        return controller;
    }
}
```

But now with the new **StructureMap**, my ReSharper suggested:

> Class 'StructureMap.ObjectFactory' is obsolete: ObjectFactory will be removed in a future 4.0 release of StructureMap. Favor the usage of the Container class for future work

The intellisense on `Container` gave me only very limited information.

How are we supposed to rewrite our **ServiceActivator** with the **Container** class?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The [static stuff is going away](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structuremap-users/S7nBib95zh0). If your not using a Service Locator of some type you're going to have implement your own "`ObjectFactory`" as [referenced here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/structuremap-users/S7nBib95zh0/wKOjzN21z_cJ):

```
public static class ObjectFactory
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Container> _containerBuilder =
            new Lazy<Container>(defaultContainer, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    public static IContainer Container
    {
       get { return _containerBuilder.Value; }
    }

     private static Container defaultContainer()
     {
        return new Container(x =>
        {
               // default config
         });
     }
}
```

**Update:** My previous answer was wrong. Thanks @JoeMighty for the heads up.

Comment: Surely this just creates a new instance of an empty container? From my experience that seems to be the case.

Comment: @JoeMightly To quote the author "ObjectFactory is just a static facade over Container anyway". However, I will throw up a gist later today that proves this.

Comment: I've read this too; however I seem to end up with an empty container. A gist demonstrating this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JoeMighty You are correct! I used Service Locator and/or the built in MVC DependencyResolver for resolution with SM3, so I never ran into this problem. However after several tests, as far as I can tell I end up with empty containers like you noted.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying and updating your answer! It's good to know I wasn't going crazy. Another pattern I've noticed is to store the container in `HttpContext.Items`.

Comment: why is ObjectFactory going away? I understand that most of its usages are wrong: service location anti-pattern; using a top-level container on a nested-container environment; (...). In some cases, such as having an IHttpModule for instance, that needs to get something from the IContainer and it's not DI-friendly, what's the suggested approach? I don't want to move my composition root and I want to use the same container context

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues I believe the gist is that ObjectFactory promotes the [service locator anti pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: @eddiegroves An IoC container is a very sharp tool, you can't just polish the edges, needs to be sharp, it's meant to be used by experienced developers. If you take the sharpness, this happens.

Comment: Service location is not and has not ever been an anti-pattern. Usage of the pattern incorrectly does not make the pattern itself wrong.

Comment: What is supposed to go in //default config?  I'm just trying to upgrade structuremap, and now our entire applications codebase is broken!  This is going to take days of work.

Comment: @TylerJones Are you using a Registry to config SM?

Comment: Yes, we are using a registry.

Comment: @TylerJones just add this then: `x.AddRegistry<MyRegistry>();` where it says // default config  MyRegistry being your registry type

Comment: @TylerJones let me know if that worked or not, I can help you offline if you still get stuck