# Get container in StructureMap 3

Tags: structuremap

I am trying to get the StructureMap 3 current container has follows:

```
public HomeController(IContainer injectedContainer) {

  IContainer container = new Container();

  var test1 = container.GetAllInstances(typeof(IMediator)); 
  var test2 = injectedContainer.GetAllInstances(typeof(IMediator));

}
```

test1 returns nothing ... test2 returns a mediator instance.

So my StructureMap 3 configuration is working fine but in some places of my application I need to get the container manually. How can I do that?

I tried the following:

```
var test3 = ObjectFactory.Container.GetAllInstances(typeof(IMediator));
```

But this returns also an empty value.

Comment: *...just curious, why have you deleted question with my answer? was it wrong? just curious...*

Comment: By mistake ... I had two windows opened and deleted the wrong question. Then I tried to recover it but was not able. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: No idea, at least I append vote to undelete... ;) anyhow, mostly wanted be sure, that my answer helped a bit... Because that's the way (syntax) I am using for setter injection `x.Policies.SetAllProperties ( set => set.TypeMatches ( type => type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsEquivalentTo(typeof(ISetting)))` ... good luck with structure map anyhow ;)
                (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you're doing in your example is creating an empty container, this is why nothing is being returned. You can see this by calling `container.WhatDoIHave();` on your container.

First of all you have to configure your container like so:

```
IContainer container = new Container();
container.Configure(c =>
{
    c.IncludeRegistry<WebsiteRegistry>();
});
```

*WebsiteRegistry.cs*

```
public class WebsiteRegistry : Registry
{
    public WebsiteRegistry()
    {
        this.Scan(x =>
        {
            x.TheCallingAssembly();
            x.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to access your instances within `ObjectFactory`. However, as you've probably noticed the `ObjectFactory` is marked for removal in future releases of StructureMap so you have a few options available to you.

A common recommendation if you're using ASP.NET MVC is to use child containers that are bound to your web applications HTTP Context (see [this tutorial for how it can be  done](http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/utilizing-structuremap-3-with-asp-net-mvc), or this [Nuget package that uses the same approach](https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap.MVC5)).

If you need to access the container manually then using this approach you're able to pull an instance of your child container from `HttpContext.Items` that gets disposed of at the end of the request.

Another option is to look at creating your own instance of the `ObjectFactory`, like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551005/963542).