# How do I use Structuremap 3 with objects that aren't friendly to constructor injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap, structuremap3

I'm moving from StructureMap 2.x to 3.x.  One major change is that using `ObjectFactory` results in the following warning:

> 'StructureMap.ObjectFactory' is obsolete: 'ObjectFactory
>   will be removed in a future 4.0 release of StructureMap. Favor the
>   usage of the Container class for future
>   work'

So in most cases, the resolution is fairly easy: pass through `IContainer` as a constructor.  Unfortunately this is not feasible for ASMX web serivces or attributes, both of which require a default constructor.  That means I'm probably stuck with the [Service Locator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), property injection, or [writing my own ObjectFactory implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550914/how-to-use-container-instead-of-objectfactory-in-structuremap-serviceactivator).

What's the preferred way to deal with this unfortunate problem?

**Edit: It's worth mentioning that my container does an Assembly scan.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per Jeremy Miller, himself](https://twitter.com/joshkodroff/status/576503467071680512):

> Assembly scanning isn’t cheap and you (almost?) always wanna cache the
>   results.  So, yeah, in that case you’re going to have to write your
>   own ObjectFactory. Someday all that bad old MS tech will go away.

So in this case, [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551005/549) is what should be done.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and sharing the answer, I've often wondered where Jeremy Miller stands on this.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way I have seen to deal with this is to use .NET routing to take control of the entry point, then make a custom `PageHandlerFactory` implementation that takes the DI container as a dependency.

The custom page handler factory will then property inject the page/service after it is instantiated but before any of its events are called.

This is almost exactly the same way that `IControllerFactory` works with DI in MVC. In MVC, the container is injected into a custom `IControllerFactory` implementation at application startup, which effectively makes it a part of the application's composition root. In the case of ASP.NET, the `IRouteHandler` would effectively be part of the composition root.

I was unable to find a link to the source where I originally saw that implementation. But [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589374/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-asp-net-web-forms) is pretty close. The primary difference is that one tries to use constructor injection, but the downside is that it requires full trust to do. I believe if you stick with property injection, you can do it with partial trust.