# 'StructureMap.ObjectFactory' is obsolete

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I implemented a interface injection using StructureMap as describe below.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => { x.For<*IRepository*>().Use<*SQLRepository*>(); });
```

But it is giving a warning as follows

> Warning   2   'StructureMap.ObjectFactory' is obsolete: 'ObjectFactory will be removed in a future 4.0 release of StructureMap. Favor the usage of the Container class for future work'.

How do I correct this by using  Container class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550914/how-to-use-container-instead-of-objectfactory-in-structuremap-serviceactivator ?

Comment: http://dennisrongo.com/resolving-the-structuremap-objectfactory-is-obsolete-warning-message/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create an instance of a container directly, per their [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20090406001252/http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/UsingTheContainerOutsideOfObjectFactory.htm).  The syntax is relatively similar.

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.ForRequestedType<IRepository>().Use<SQLRepository>();
});
```

Comment: Your documentation link is 404 not found