# Registering and Resolving a Service with delegate type constructor parameter using Structuremap

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, structuremap, constructor-injection

I have following service class:

```
public class MyService : IService
{
   public MyService(Func<string,bool> question)
   {
      ....
   }
   ...
}
```

When I use this service in my WinForms application I want to pass following code as `MyService` constructor parameter

```
(string question) => 
{ 
   var questionForm = new SimpleQuestionForm(question);
   if(questionForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      return true;
   else
      return false; 
}
```

How can I tell to the StructureMap that what is my `question` delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined following Registry class in my WindowsForm project:

```
public class WinUIRegistry:Registry
{
    public WinUIRegistry()
    {
        bool SimpleQuestionDelegate(string question)
        {
            var questionForm = new SimpleQuestionForm();
            questionForm.SetData(question);
            return questionForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes;
        }

        For<IService>()
            .Use<MyService>()
            .Ctor<Func<string, bool>>().Is(SimpleQuestionDelegate);
    }
}
```

And then added registry to the [ObjectFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550914/how-to-use-container-instead-of-objectfactory-in-structuremap-serviceactivator/25551005#25551005)'s Container by following code in the start of the project's `Program.cs`:

```
ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(x=>x.IncludeRegistry<WinUIRegistry>());
```

For relosving:

```
var service = ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IService>();
```