# StructureMap in ASP.NET Web API 2 without a reference to System.Web.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-web-api, structuremap, structuremap3

The StructureMap.WebApi2 package has a dependency to StructureMap.MVC5 which in return has a dependency to System.Web.Mvc.

As we are building a Web API-only project we don't want to include the System.Web.Mvc assembly.

Is it possible to use StructureMap in Web API 2 without this dependency?

Comment: Autofac is a good Ioc for Web Api. It's worth the try.

Comment: I agree. We went with StructureMap since the other teams are using it.

Comment: Autofac is far better in documentation than structuremap,  most of the structuremap examples are old and useless for version 3 for example.

Comment: I have noticed that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly no.

`StructureMap` is made for `MVC` so it obviously depends on it.

Why do you insist on using `StructureMap` though? All it does is `DI` and there are many other options to do `DI` in `Web API`, like `Ninject` and `Unity`.

Comment: I have previously successfully used Ninject and Autofac. Since other teams here are using StructureMap this was the natural choice. Maybe it is time to reconsider :)

Comment: Maybe in time StructureMap will offer a Web API version, until then you are sadly stuck with some other solution.

Comment: Could the answer here be a workaround for now? Or will it require the same dependencies?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896758/webapi-apicontroller-with-structuremap

Comment: The dependencies will be the same. You could try to remove the reference yourself but who knows. I still consider that you'll be better off with a solution made for Web API.

Comment: Ok. Yes, I will go with Autofac instead.

Answer (score 0):

Autofac is a good Ioc for Web Api, and Autofac is far better in documentation than structuremap, most of the structuremap examples are old and useless for version 3 for example.

- [Here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html), you can find a quick start for using Autofac.
- [Here](http://alexmg.com/owin-support-for-the-web-api-2-and-mvc-5-integrations-in-autofac/), you can find a good start-up for using Autofac with OWIN.

Hope that helps.